# Javascript and print on the page

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I started to learn javascript and I saw the following code in one of Javascript books:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Simple JavaScript Example</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <p>Printed before JavaScript is run.</p>
    <p>
        <script type=”text/javascript”>
        document.write(“Printed by JavaScript.”);
        </script>
    </p>
    <p>Printed after JavaScript is run.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the book, three lines has to be printed. However, when I open this html file in the browser I see only the first and the last lines. The line "Printed by JavaScript" doesn't show.

Do you have any idea what can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because you used incorrect double quotes (wrong copy-paste from the book sample):

```
”
```

should become:

```
"
```

so that you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("Printed by JavaScript.");
</script>
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. The problem is with "text/javascript". I just did an automatic copy-paste from the pdf file of the book. Maybe it's a typo in the book.